# Django Database get data

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get all my data out of the database in a array or list format.
Such that I can make an for loop in the html to loop through all the names in the database.

I tried with:

```
all_name = name.objects.all()
```

the output will be shown as

> <QuerySet [<allName: name1>, < allName: name2>, < allName: name3>]>

However I want to get something like:

> name1;
> name2; name3

What I did next is to use the .get function:

```
all_name = name.objects.get(id=1)
```

my name model:

```
class name(models.Model):
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return (self.firstname)
```

This gives me only one object with the given id.
Is there a way to get what I am looking for and display my array/list with a forloop in a html file?

Comment: Please share your `name` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try for `Name` model with consider `allName` as a attribute/column

```
list(Name.objects.all().values_list('allName', flat=True))
```

or

```
Name.objects.all().values_list('allName')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the strings that originate from the database with:

```
'; '.join(map(str, name.objects.all()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Many:

`name_list = Name.objects.all().values_list('firstname', flat=True))`

One:

```
query = name.objects.get(id=1)

name = query.firstname
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.